# How to remove suggestion array values that are already used javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am just create tagging system like stack overflow,Well how it works when an value is there in tagname  box the In suggestion box that value will not appear.
That's the thing I am trying to implement.

loaded Tags name from database

```
 this.props.loadedTags.suggestionTags//[{id:dasdv,tagName:"hello"},{id:2154,tagName:"sql"}]
```

the tags already selected

> ```
> this.props.photos.postTags//["sql"]
> ```

So we have to fileter suggestion like this

> `this.props.loadedTags.suggestionTags//[{id:dasdv,tagName:"hello"}]`

How to Do this

```
this.props.loadedTags.suggestionTags.map((data) => {
               console.log(this.props.photos.postTags);
               if(this.props.photos.postTags != data.tagName){
                   return <li onClick={(e) => this.handleTagClick(e,data.tagName)} key={data.id}>{data.tagName}</li>
               }

            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) :

```
this.props.loadedTags.suggestionTags.map((data) => {
  if (this.props.photos.postTags.indexOf(data.tagName) === -1) {
    return <li onClick = {
      (e) => this.handleTagClick(e, data.tagName)
    }
    key = {
      data.id
    } > {
      data.tagName
    } < /li>
  }
})
```

Comment: Its working ,But why -1 could you pls explain or provide any example

Comment: Click on the link in the answer, it points to the function's documentation :) `indexOf` returns -1 if the provided value wasn't found in the array, otherwise, it returns the key of the corresponding value.